# Skip some validations on different controllers accessing the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am not sure if this problem is due to a lack of knowledge or a problem in my design.

Essentially, I want my users to be able to login and be given a default role. Later on, they can become "Managers" and need to go to a second sign up form to achieve this.

However, the difference between a standard user and a manager is very minimal in terms of what data they have (but very different in terms of what permissions they are allowed). Therefore, I have chosen to use a single User model for both of them and then two controllers, users_controller and managers_controller, to serve the two different sign up forms and the resulting create requests. It might be that this just the wrong way to handle this situation.

I have some validations setup in this model and I want to be able to ensure that some of these validations are fired for on the initial sign up form (when a guest becomes a user, via the users_controller) and the rest are fired on the second sign up form (when a user becomes a manager, via the managers_controller). However, I use, for example `validates_presence_of` then it checks the validation on both forms and complains that I am not, for example, asking my normal users for a date of birth.

I know how to skip checks on particular actions but how to do I this for different controllers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Validations are on the model side, so they are independent on controllers. BTW it seems that you are speaking about role based approach.

You can achieve your goals by using `if` statement on validations.

```
validates :date_of_birth, :presence => true, :if => :manager?

def manager?
  # It actually  depends on your design. 
  # You can use any authorization library.

  self.role == "manager"
end
```

For example, the popular one is [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan).

Comment: Wow I had no idea you could do that. Wonderful! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that User has some kind of attribute or association where its roles are stored. Every validator in rails (like validates_presence_of) can be conditional in a way that it is only fired when the Proc/Method you supply via the :if option returns true. Within such a Proc, you could check, if the user is actually trying to become a "manager".

I recently had a similar problem, where validations had to be different depending on the state a particular model instance would be in. Have a look at the state_machine (http://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine) gem which provides support for that. Perhaps this suits your scenario better.

Comment: Interesting, I had often wondered about state machine. Sounds like something worth looking into.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
validates_presence_of :something, :if=>:manager?

def manager?
  self.manager
end
```

Or to skip validations specifically you can do

```
@user.save(false)
```

from one of the controllers

Comment: It's a bad approach to skip all validations. I don't recommend to do so.